# Problem with parsing JSON from the backend

Tags: java, android, retrofit

As I have been working on an Android project in which there is a need to receive `JSON` from the backend, I prepared the `JSON` in Java using Spring Boot 2.1.7.

From the backend side it is ok, works. But from the Android side, I cannot parse the variable.
When I try to parse the variable using construction:

```java
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(variable);
```

then I recieve the information that JSONArray() in JSONArray cannot be applied to `com.package.Model`. I have also tried different approach to this problem:

**Backend**

```java
@RequestMapping( value = "/approachh", method = RequestMethod.GET )
@ResponseBody
public List<Categories> getList() {
    List<Categories> categoriesList = new ArrayList<>();
    categoriesList = categoriesRepository.findAll();
    return categoriesList;
}
```

**JSON response**

```js
{
  "List":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "categoryName":"Categories1",
      "subCategories":[
        {
          "id":1,
          "subCategoriesName":"lkjasdf"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "categoryName":"Categories2",
      "subCategories":[
        {
          "id":2,
          "subCategoriesName":"lkjasdasdfasf"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Client (Android)**

```java
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(variable); 
// then I recieve the information that JSONArray() in JSONArray cannot be applied to com.package.Model. I have also tried different approach to this problem:

String json = "";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Type showType = new TypeToken<Collection<Approach>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Approach> approaches = gson.fromJson(json, showType);
String catName = String.valueOf(approaches.get(0).getCategoryName());

// but when I tried to receive information about the catName, there was 0.
Log.d("catName","catName" + catName);
```

### Approach.class

```
public class Approach {


@SerializedName("categoryName")
@Expose
private String categoryName;

@SerializedName("subCategories")
@Expose
private List<SubCategories> subCategories;

public Approach(String categoryName, List<SubCategories> subCategories) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
    this.subCategories = subCategories;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}

public List<SubCategories> getSubCategories() {
    return subCategories;
}

public void setSubCategories(List<SubCategories> subCategories) {
    this.subCategories = subCategories;
}
```

}

### SubCategories.class

```
public class SubCategories {


@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;

@SerializedName("subCategoriesName")
@Expose
private String subCategoriesName;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSubCategoriesName() {
    return subCategoriesName;
}

public void setSubCategoriesName(String subCategoriesName) {
    this.subCategoriesName = subCategoriesName;
}
```

}

### MainActivity.class Android

### method in which I connect with retrofit to localhost to retrieve information

```
private void fetchhhhData() {

    compositeDisposable.add(iMyAPI.getAll()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Consumer<Approach>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void accept(Approach approach) throws Exception {


            showData(Collections.singletonList(approach));

        }
    }));

}
```

### MainActivity.class Android

### showData()

```
  private void showData(List<Approach> approaches) {

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(approaches);



    for (int i=1; i<= jsonArray.length() - 1; i++) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String categ = jsonObject.get("List").toString();

             Log.d("categ","categ" + categ);

         //   String catName = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("List"));


     //       String catName = jsonObject.getString("categoryName");

      //      Log.d("catName","catName" + catName);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

Could you please point me out, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Provide the Approach class

Comment: Rajnish suryavanshi thanks for the answer, just added the Approach class and SubCategories

Comment: Try to add a debugger to check the value of the variable, the json array formed from the variable

Comment: Please add `variable` declaration and initialisation

Comment: I added two methods: fetchhhhData() and showData(). In fetchhhhData() I try to retrieve the information, and send the variable 'approach' to the showData(). In showData() I try to retrieve information from it. But it doesn't work. None of the information show up in the console.

Comment: what is `variable` in **Client (Android)** ?

Comment: Firstly, In you *Client (Android)*, you are doing `String json = ""`, the rest won't work obviously... Secondly, if you Gson library, your **JSON Respone** is an object, not an array, so doing `new TypeToken<Collection<Approach>>(){}.getType()` won't work, you have to create a new class that represents your response.

Comment: having said variable I meant the approach of the Approach.class

Answer (score 0):

Here you have working example. It is much simpler if you introduce one more class `CategoriesResponse` (see below).

Then make sure that the `json` argument passed to `gson.fromJson(json, CategoriesResponse.class);` is actual json String or `Reader` or `JsonObject` retrieved from your endpoint.

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        String json = "{\n" + "  \"List\":[\n" + "    {\n" + "      \"id\":1,\n" + "      \"categoryName"
                + "\":\"Categories1\",\n"
                + "      \"subCategories\":[\n" + "        {\n" + "          \"id\":1,\n"
                + "          \"subCategoriesName\":\"lkjasdf\"\n" + "        }\n" + "      ]\n" + "    },\n" + "    {\n"
                + "      \"id\":2,\n" + "      \"categoryName\":\"Categories2\",\n" + "      \"subCategories\":[\n"
                + "        {\n" + "          \"id\":2,\n" + "          \"subCategoriesName\":\"lkjasdasdfasf\"\n"
                + "        }\n" + "      ]\n" + "    }\n" + "  ]\n" + "}";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CategoriesResponse gsonResponse = gson.fromJson(json, CategoriesResponse.class);

        assertEquals(2, gsonResponse.categories.size());

    }

    public class Approach {

        @SerializedName("categoryName") @Expose private String categoryName;
        @SerializedName("subCategories") @Expose private List<SubCategories> subCategories;

        public Approach(String categoryName, List<SubCategories> subCategories) {
            this.categoryName = categoryName;
            this.subCategories = subCategories;
        }
    }

    public class SubCategories {

        @SerializedName("id") @Expose private int id;
        @SerializedName("subCategoriesName") @Expose private String subCategoriesName;
    }

    public class CategoriesResponse {

        @SerializedName("List") @Expose private List<Approach> categories;
    }
```